# Multiline Regex matches first occurance but can't match second

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string in the format below. (I added the markers to get the newlines to show up correctly)

```
-- START BELOW THIS LINE --
2013-08-28 00:00:00 - Tom Smith (Work notes)
Blah blah

b;lah blah

2013-08-27 00:00:00 - Tom Smith (Work notes)
ZXcZXCZXCZX
ZXcZXCZX
ZXCZXcZXc
ZXCZXC


-- END ABOVE THIS LINE --
```

I am trying to get a regular expression that will allow me to extract the information from the two separate parts of the string.

The following expression matches the first portion successfully:

```
^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}) - (.*) \\(Work notes\\)\n([\\w\\W]*)(?=\n\n\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} - .* \\(Work notes\\)\n)
```

I am trying to figure out a way that I can modify it to get the second part of the string. I have tried things like what is below, but it ends up extending the match all the way to the end of the string. It is like it is giving preference to the expression following the OR.

```
^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}) - (.*) \\(Work notes\\)\n([\\w\\W]*)(?:(?=\n\n\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} - .* \\(Work notes\\)\n)|\n\\Z)
```

Any help would be appreciated

**-- EDIT --**

Here is a copy of the test program I created to try and get this correct. I also added a 3rd message and my RegEx above breaks in that case.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegExTest
{
  class MainClass
  {
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
      string str = "2013-08-28 10:50:13 - Tom Smith (Work notes)\nWhat's up? \nHow you been?\n\n2013-08-19 10:21:03 - Tom Smith (Work notes)\nWork Notes\n\n2013-08-19 10:10:48 - Tom Smith (Work notes)\nGood day\n\n";
      var regex = new Regex ("^(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}) - (.*) \\(Work notes\\)\n([\\w\\W]*)\n\n(?=\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} - .* \\(Work notes\\)\n)",RegexOptions.Multiline);

      foreach (Match match in regex.Matches(str))
      {
        if (match.Success)
        {
          for (var i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
          {
            Console.WriteLine('>'+match.Groups [i].Value);
          }
        }
      }

      Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

**-- EDIT --**

Just to make it clear, the data I am trying to extract is the Date and Timestamp (as one item), the name, and the "body" from each "paragraph".

Comment: Can we see your calling code?

Comment: Could you post the exact code you're using to construct the regex object and to perform the match? You're likely not using the correct flags.

Comment: What can appear in the body of the each paragraph, anything ?

Comment: @Sniffer Yes, any sort of string can appear in the body. If that weren't the case this would be a lot easier.

Comment: @Jason Have you tried my expression and if yes then did you find any problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty beefy piece of regex you've got here.

While you *can* do regex over multiple lines, it just complicates things. Additionally, because you have repetitive patterns, it would be cleaner to split your string on the newline character, and then just match each line.

Eventually, if you intend to ingest this from a file, it will be easy to match each line of the file, rather than reading in the whole file and then matching.

Here's what I would do:

```
var regex = new Regex ("(\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}) - (.*?) \\(Work notes\\)");

var lines = str.split(new char[] {'\n'});

foreach (var line in lines)
{
  var match = regex.Match(line);

  if (match.Success)
  {
    for (var i = 0; i < match.Groups.Count; i++)
    {
      Console.WriteLine('>' + match.Groups[i].Value);
    }

    // will preface the body after each header
    Console.WriteLine(">");
  }
  else
  {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
  }
}
```

As far as your regex goes, I maintained the original groups you had, so we get the Date/timestamp in one group, and the name in the other. The body does not get matched to a group, but it would be trivial to construct a string that is the body.

1. `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})` Matching Group 1.
2. `-` Matched, but not grouped.
3. `(.*?)` Matching Group 2.
4. `\(Work notes\)` Matched, but not grouped.

Comment: I originally was doing it line by line, but my boss thought a multi-line regex would be less confusing. I now doubt that very much.

Answer (score 0):

Regex is not really the right solution for this, but if you must...

Your problem is a combination of regex greediness and starting the match with ^. If it starts with ^ it needs it to start the string and it won't match anywhere else.

The greediness of `.*` can be fixed by making it `.*?` instead.

Try this:

```
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) - (.*?) \(Work notes\)\n([\w\W]*?)((?=\n\n\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} - .*? \(Work notes\)\n)|((\s{0,})$))
```

Comment: That gets it there, but it splits the "body" into separate groups. If you have a method other than RegEx please feel free to suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get an expression working but it looks a bit scary I guess:

```
@"([0-9\s:-]+)(?>\s-\s)(?>[^\n\r]+[\r\n]*)((?=[^0-9]+(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}|$))[\s\S])+"
```

The `@` before the expression to make this a verbatim string so you won't have to double escape everything.

**Note:** This is by no means the right way to go about doing this, but I wanted to try out anyway.

Comment: Sorry, this didn't do it. It wasn't getting all of the body if I remember correctly.